# Enabling Xdebug 3.2 results in loads of warnings for unused variables

Tags: php, xdebug

I've just upgraded from PHP 7.4 & Xdebug 3.0 to PHP 8.1 & Xdebug 3.2.
I never had this issue with earlier versions.

This is my php.ini:

```ini
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=php_xdebug-3.2.0RC2-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

And for some reason, even if I don't send a `XDEBUG_SESSION=VSCODE` cookie, the warnings still appear.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/r18eQT6.png]

Disabling Xdebug disables the errors.

I want to keep Xdebug enabled but I don't want to see pointless warnings about unused variables.

EDIT - Sorry. Kept seeing 'unused' instead of 'undefined'... My bad!

Comment: Side note: *"...pointless warnings about unused variables"* They are not "unused", they are undefined variables. Which means that you have some logic flaw. Ideally you want to get rid of these warnings to have a cleaner code (if it's yours, ofc)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These warnings are not caused by Xdebug's step debugger, but rather through your PHP's own error handler (and configured level). Xdebug only shows these when plain PHP would also have done so.

You should also fix these warnings in your code, as they indicate that you're having some sort of logic flaw, or a potential one.